# Subtracting column from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I'm trying to subtract values of one of `DataFrame` `columns` from whole `DataFrame`. Intuitively this seems like a non-problem for me, but somehow I can't figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": range(1, 10),
    "b": range(2, 11),
    "c": range(11, 20)
})

print x - x['b']
```

And what I get is surprisingly:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   a   b   c
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Instead of `DataFrame` with `columns:` (a-b), (b-b), (c-b).

I just started playing with Python. Can you tell me what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to see my answer here which shows what's happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954263/what-does-the-term-broadcasting-mean-in-pandas-documentation/29955358#29955358

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
x.subtract(x['b'], axis=0)

   a  b  c
0 -1  0  9
1 -1  0  9
2 -1  0  9
3 -1  0  9
4 -1  0  9
5 -1  0  9
6 -1  0  9
7 -1  0  9
8 -1  0  9
```

See [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#flexible-binary-operations) for details on the `axis=0` parameter, which ensures that the `index` of `x['B']` aligns with the `DataFrame` `index`, and not the `columns` as per default.

To make the `-` operator work, you'd have to:

```
(x.T - x['b']).T
```

Comment: Please just let me know if you find the answer acceptable, or if you need any additional detail.

Comment: Work's great! I was going to tick the post, but I had to wait like 10 minutes and I got sunked into something else. Thanks a lot!