# Pandas Can't use Apply on Transposed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple function:

```
def f(returns):
    base = (1 + returns.sum()) / (1 + returns).prod()
    base = pd.Series([base] * len(returns))
    exp = returns.abs() / returns.abs().sum()

return (1 + returns) * base.pow(exp) - 1.0
```

and a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[.1,.2,.3],[.4,.5,.6],[.7,.8,.9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

I can do this:

```
df.apply(f)

          A         B         C
0  0.084169  0.159224  0.227440
1  0.321130  0.375803  0.426375
2  0.535960  0.567532  0.599279
```

However, the transposition:

```
df.transpose().apply(f)
```

produces an unexpected result:

```
    0   1   2
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
A NaN NaN NaN
B NaN NaN NaN
C NaN NaN NaN
```

Now, I can manually transpose the DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1., 4., 7.],[2., 5., 8.], [3., 6., 9.]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2.apply(f)

          A         B         C
0  0.628713  1.516577  2.002160
1  0.989529  1.543616  1.936151
2  1.160247  1.499530  1.836141
```

I don't understand why I can't simply transpose and then apply the function to each row of the DataFrame. In fact, I don't know why I can't do this either:

```
df.apply(f, axis=1)

    0   1   2   A   B   C
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: because it's trying to align the returned series against the original index, as you've transposed the columns and indices around they no longer align so you get an expanded df filled with nan's

Comment: @EdChum: Can you tell me which line is the problem? What about `df.apply(f, axis=1)` (see edited code at the bottom). Is that failing for the same reason?

Comment: same reason, see related answer of mine that demonstrates how broadcasting and alignment works here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954263/what-does-the-term-broadcasting-mean-in-pandas-documentation/29955358#29955358

Comment: your `base` calculation returns a series with index `[0,1,2]` but  `returns` has index `['A','B','C']` so you get this stacked series where nothing aligns, hence the `NaN`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EdChum says, the problem is pandas is trying to align the index of the Series you create inside `f` with the index of the DataFrame.  This coincidentally works in your first example because you don't specify an index in the `Series` call, so it uses the default `0, 1, 2`, which happens to be the same as your original DF.  If your original DF has some other index, it will fail right away:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[.1,.2,.3],[.4,.5,.6],[.7,.8,.9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[8, 9, 10])
>>> df.apply(f)
     A   B   C
0  NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN
8  NaN NaN NaN
9  NaN NaN NaN
10 NaN NaN NaN
```

To fix it, explicitly create the new Series with the same index as your DF.  Change the line inside `d` to:

```
base = pd.Series([base] * len(returns), index=returns.index)
```

Then:

```
>>> df.apply(f)
           A         B         C
8   0.084169  0.159224  0.227440
9   0.321130  0.375803  0.426375
10  0.535960  0.567532  0.599279
>>> df.T.apply(f)
          8         9         10
A  0.087243  0.293863  0.453757
B  0.172327  0.359225  0.505245
C  0.255292  0.421544  0.553746
```