# Divide Dataframe by a series sharing index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to divide a DataFrame by one of its columns (a Series), they both share the index, so I expect the result has the shape of the original DataFrame.

This code shows what I did:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
ix = range(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=ix, columns=cols, data=np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 4)))

print(df / df['A'])
```

The result is something like that:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

But I expect something like that:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1  ..  ..  ..
1   1  ..  ..  ..
2   1  ..  ..  ..
3   1  ..  ..  ..
4   1  ..  ..  ..
5   1  ..  ..  ..
6   1  ..  ..  ..
7   1  ..  ..  ..
8   1  ..  ..  ..
9  89  94  14  44
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

use `div` with `axis=0`, it's aligning on the columns hence you get the `0...9` and original columns, you should use `div` and explicitly pass `axis=0` so it broadcasts along the index:

```
In [58]:

, axis=0
df.div(df['A'], axis=0)
Out[58]:
     A          B          C         D
0  1.0   0.818182   1.681818  0.431818
1  1.0   1.562500   0.625000  1.468750
2  1.0  17.000000   5.400000  2.800000
3  1.0   9.428571  13.857143  8.285714
4  1.0   0.256098   0.085366  1.146341
5  1.0  27.000000  21.500000  7.500000
6  1.0   0.444444   1.236111  1.041667
7  1.0   0.268293   0.048780  1.146341
8  1.0   0.505051   0.434343  0.101010
9  1.0   0.673684   0.378947  0.873684
```

You can see a related question: [What does the term "broadcasting" mean in Pandas documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954263/what-does-the-term-broadcasting-mean-in-pandas-documentation) that illustrates the broadcasting rules