# Subtract two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My df looks as follows:

```
Index    Country    Val1  Val2 ... Val10
1        Australia  1     3    ... 5
2        Bambua     12    33   ... 56
3        Tambua     14    34   ... 58
```

I'd like to substract Val10 from Val1 for each country, so output looks like:

```
Country    Val10-Val1
Australia  4
Bambua     23
Tambua     24
```

So far I've got:

```
def myDelta(row):
    data = row[['Val10', 'Val1']]
    return pd.Series({'Delta': np.subtract(data)})

def runDeltas():
    myDF = getDF() \
        .apply(myDelta, axis=1) \
        .sort_values(by=['Delta'], ascending=False)
    return myDF
```

runDeltas results in this error:

```
ValueError: ('invalid number of arguments', u'occurred at index 9')
```

What's the proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["Australia", 1, 3, 5],
                   ["Bambua", 12, 33, 56],
                   ["Tambua", 14, 34, 58]
                  ], columns=["Country", "Val1", "Val2", "Val10"]
                 )
```

It comes down to a simple [broadcasting operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29955358):

```
>>> df["Val1"] - df["Val10"]
0    -4
1   -44
2   -44
dtype: int64
```

You can also store this into a new column with:

```
>>> df['Val_1_minus_10'] = df['Val1'] - df['Val10']
>>> df
     Country  Val1  Val2  Val10  Val_1_minus_10
0  Australia     1     3      5              -4
1     Bambua    12    33     56             -44
2     Tambua    14    34     58             -44
```

Answer (score 16):

Using this as the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Australia", 1, 3, 5],
               ["Bambua", 12, 33, 56],
               ["Tambua", 14, 34, 58]
              ], columns=["Country", "Val1", "Val2", "Val10"]
             )
```

You can also do the subtraction and put it into a new column as follows.

```
>>>df['Val_Diff'] = df['Val10'] - df['Val1']

    Country     Val1    Val2  Val10 Val_Diff
0   Australia   1       3      5    4
1   Bambua      12      33     56   44
2   Tambua      14      34     58   44
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by using lambda function and assign to new column.

```
df['Val10-Val1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Val10'] - x['Val1'], axis=1)
print df
```

Comment: Note: vectorization over a Pandas Series (such as df[col2]-df[col1]) will generally have better performance than using DataFrame apply with axis=1.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use **pandas.DataFrame.assign** function: e,g

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["Australia", 1, 3, 5],
                   ["Bambua", 12, 33, 56],
                   ["Tambua", 14, 34, 58]
                  ], columns=["Country", "Val1", "Val2", "Val10"]
                 )

df = df.assign(Val10_minus_Val1 = df['Val10'] - df['Val1'])
```

The best part of assign is you can add as many assignments as you wish. e.g. getting both the difference and then the log of it

```
df = df.assign(Val10_minus_Val1 = df['Val10'] - df['Val1'], log_result = lambda x: np.log(x.Val10_minus_Val1) )
```

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Though it's an old question but pandas allows subtracting two `DataFrame`s or `Series`s using [pandas.DataFrame.subtract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html?highlight=subtract#pandas.DataFrame.subtract)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["Australia", 1, 3, 5],
                   ["Bambua", 12, 33, 56],
                   ["Tambua", 14, 34, 58]
                  ], columns=["Country", "Val1", "Val2", "Val10"]
                 )


df["Val1"].subtract(df["Val2"])
```

Output:

```
0    -2
1   -21
2   -20
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) here:

```
In [12]: df.eval('Val10_minus_Val1 = Val10-Val1', inplace=True)

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
     Country  Val1  Val2  Val10  Val10_minus_Val1
0  Australia     1     3      5                 4
1     Bambua    12    33     56                44
2     Tambua    14    34     58                44
```

Since `inplace=True` you don't have to assign it back to `df`.

Answer (score 0):

What I have faced today, makes me ambitious to share it with you. As people mentioned above you can used easily:

```
df['Val10-Val1'] = df['Val10']-df['Val1']
```

but sometimes you might need to use apply function, so you might use the following line:

```
df['Val10-Val1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Val10']-row['Val1'])
```

Comment: Be careful! Your code `df['Val10-Val1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Val10']-row['Val1'])` will produce `KeyError: ('Val10', 'occurred at index Country')`, because you have not specified an axis correctly. The functional code is following: `df['Val10-Val1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Val10'] - row['Val1'], axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another, more recent, way of doing this, is by using the [`sub()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html)-method:

```
df['Val_1_minus_10'] = df.loc[:,'Val1'].sub(df.loc[:,'Val10'])
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

"Equivalent to `dataframe - other`, but with support to substitute a fill_value for missing data in one of the inputs. With reverse version, `rsub`."