# Iteratively combine text in first column with existing text in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I am in the process of creating a python script that extracts data from a poorly designed output file (which I can't change) from a piece of equipment within our research lab. I would like to include a way to iteratively combine the text in the first column of a dataframe (example below) with each other column in the dataframe.

A simple example of the dataframe:

| Filename | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Sheet(1) | Sheet(2) | Sheet(3) | Sheet(4) | .... |
| b | Sheet(1) | Sheet(2) | -------- | -------- | .... |
| c | Sheet(1) | Sheet(2) | Sheet(3) | Sheet(4) | .... |
| d | Sheet(1) | Sheet(2) | Sheet(3) | -------- | .... |
| e | Sheet(1) | Sheet(2) | Sheet(3) | Sheet(4) | .... |
| f | Sheet(1) | -------- | -------- | -------- | .... |

What I am looking to produce:

| Filename | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a_Sheet(1) | a_Sheet(2) | a_Sheet(3) | a_Sheet(4) | .... |
| b | b_Sheet(1) | b_Sheet(2) | -------- | -------- | .... |
| c | c_Sheet(1) | c_Sheet(2) | c_Sheet(3) | c_Sheet(4) | .... |
| d | d_Sheet(1) | d_Sheet(2) | d_Sheet(3) | -------- | .... |
| e | e_Sheet(1) | e_Sheet(2) | e_Sheet(3) | e_Sheet(4) | .... |
| f | f_Sheet(1) | -------- | -------- | -------- | .... |

Answer (score 4):

- Use `.apply` to prepend the `'Filename'` string to the other columns.
- Of the current answers, the solution from [Mykola Zotko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8973620/mykola-zotko) is the fastest solution, tested against a 3 column dataframe with 100k rows.
- If your dataframe has, undesired strings (e.g. `'--------'`), then use something like `df.replace('--------', pd.NA, inplace=True)`, before combining the column strings.

  - If the final result must have `'--------'`, then use `df.fillna('--------', inplace=True)` at the end. This will be better than trying to iteratively deal with them.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Filename': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c1': ['s1'] * 3, 'c2': ['s2', np.nan, 's2']})

# display(df)
  Filename  c1   c2
0        a  s1   s2
1        b  s1  NaN
2        c  s1   s2

# prepend the filename strings to the other columns
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: df.Filename + '_' + x)

# display(df)
  Filename    c1    c2
0        a  a_s1  a_s2
1        b  b_s1   NaN
2        c  c_s1  c_s2
```

### `%%timeit` test against other answers

```py
# test data with 100k rows
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Filename': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c1': ['s1'] * 3, 'c2': ['s2'] * 3})] * 33333).reset_index(drop=True)

# Solution from Trenton
%%timeit
df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: df.Filename + '_' + x)
[out]:
33.6 ms ± 1.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Solution from Mykola
%%timeit
df['Filename'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1) + '_' + df.loc[:, 'c1':]
[out]:
29.6 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Solution from Alex
%%timeit
df.loc[:, cols].apply(lambda s: df["Filename"].str.cat(s, sep="_"))
[out]:
45.3 ms ± 1.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# iterating the columns in a for-loop
def test(d):
    for cols in d.columns[1:]:
        d[cols]=d['Filename'] + '_' + d[cols]
    return d

%%timeit
test(df)
[out]:
53.8 ms ± 4.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you have the following data frame:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a    x    y    z
1    b    x    y    z
2    c    x    y  NaN
```

You can use [broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29954263/8973620):

```
df.loc[:, 'col2':] = df['col1'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1) + '_' + df.loc[:, 'col2':]
```

Result:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a  a_x  a_y  a_z
1    b  b_x  b_y  b_z
2    c  c_x  c_y  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for cols in df.loc[:,'1':]:
    df[cols]=df['Filename']+'_'+df[cols]
```

Comment: This produces a TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on Index with these indexers [1] of type int

Comment: @lake08 is your column names of type `int` or `str`? probably `str` . so you can replace 1 with '1' inside `loc`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, they are str's. I tried replacing 1 with '1' in loc and throws a KeyError: '1'. An example of an actual "filename" from the data set is "Highland Range_Site 5_2021-01-14_08-59-20.xlsx" is this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28103548)

Comment: @Bijendra: Why do you say that? This appears to be an answer to me.

Comment: @JeremyCaney. my bad, was reviewing in bulk and would have mistakenly marked it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've represented the `--------` as `np.NaN`. You should be able to label these as NaN when you [load the file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), see `nan_values`.

This is the dict for the DataFrame:

```py
d = {
    1: [nan, "Sheet(1)", nan],
    2: [nan, "Sheet(2)", nan],
    3: ["Sheet(3)", nan, "Sheet(3)"],
    4: ["Sheet(4)", nan, nan],
    "Filename": ["a", "b", "c"],
}
df = pd.DatFrame(d)
```

Then we can:

- Make a mask of the columns we want to change, everything but `Filename`

```py
cols = df.columns != "Filename"
# array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

- Apply a function, which uses [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```py
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].apply(lambda s: df["Filename"].str.cat(s, sep="_"))
```

this function takes each column specified in `cols` and concatenates it with the `Filename` column.

Which produces:

```py
            1           2           3           4 Filename
0         NaN         NaN  a_Sheet(3)  a_Sheet(4)        a
1  b_Sheet(1)  b_Sheet(2)         NaN         NaN        b
2         NaN         NaN  c_Sheet(3)         NaN        c
```