# How does `s = (iowa_file_data.dtypes == 'object')` make `s` a variable of type `Series`

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote (copied) a code

```
iowa_file_data = pd.read_csv(iowa_train_prices_file_path)
    #dtypes is a Series
    s = (iowa_file_data.dtypes == 'object')
```

I get that `iowa_file_data` is of type `dataframe` and `dtypes` is a `Series`. But how did `s` become a `Series`? Does output of `(iowa_file_data.dtypes == 'object')` make a `Series`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas (and the underlying numpy) use special overloads of `__eq__` operators. The goal is that most operation between numpy arrays, dataframes or series still return an object of same type. And when you have one Series on one side of the operator and a scalar on the other side, the scalar is *broadcasted* over the missing dimension to build a Series of same size (and index) as the initial series, where all cells have the value (and the type) of the scalar.

So yes, if `ser` is a `Series`, `ser == 'object'` is also a `Series` of same size and index as `ser`.

Answer (score 0):

pandas uses `array-broadcasting` similar to numpy... as such, operations are performed on each element rather than on the object itself. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29955358/9703451 for example)

what do you try to accomplish with your query?

Answer (score 0):

It may have overloaded `__eq__` operator.

See this example

```py
class A:
    def __eq__(self, o: object) -> bool:
        if isinstance(o, str):
            return 13
        return super().__eq__(o)


a = A()

# returns False
print(a == 2)

# returns 13 because of overriden __eq__ in A class
print(a == 's')
```

More info: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).