# Checking if elements in an array exist in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas Dataframe and a pandas Series that looks like below.

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c','d'],'col2':['b','c','e','f'],'col3':['d','f','g','a']})

  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b    d
1    b    c    f
2    c    e    g
3    d    f    a

df1 = pd.Series(['b','g','g'], index=['col1','col2','col3'])

col1    b
col2    g
col3    g
dtype: object
```

As you can see, the columns of `df0` and the indices of `df1` are the same. For each index of `df1`, I want to know if the value at that index exists in the corresponding column of `df0`. So, `df1.col1` is `b` and we need to look for `b` only in `df0.col1` and check if it exists.

Desired output:

```
array([True, False, True])
```

Is there a way to do this without using a loop? Maybe a method native to numpy or pandas?

Comment: Could use something like `melt` to convert both data frames from wide to long, and then `join` them on col and value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954263/what-does-the-term-broadcasting-mean-in-pandas-documentation):

```
(df0 == df1).any().values
```

It also works with NumPy ndarrays:

```
assert (df0.columns == df1.columns).all()

(df0.values == df1.values).any(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([ True, False,  True])
```

Comment: This is virtually the same as [@StevenS' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69232614/16343464). Or should I propose `df0.__eq__(df1).any()`? :p

Comment: I personally think this doesn't have an added value here, if all the syntax variants were proposed for each answer this would be unbearable (I am just saying this as your answered much later than the other answer). Eventually you could add a comment in (or edit) the other answer

Comment: `eq` and `==` are different functions and you can get different results with parameters in `eq`. Plus I explain that you use broadcasting here.

Comment: Could you explain how ‘eq’ and ‘==‘ are different? Also, for the numpy case, why does it work without ‘[None,:]’? Sorry, these are really basic questions.

Comment: You can change the `axis` parameter in `eq` and get different results `df0.eq(df1, axis='rows')`. It works without `[None,:]` because of broadcasting (it does it automatically).

Answer (score 5):

Pandas' [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) method is probably the simplest.

```
df0.eq(df1).any()

col1     True
col2    False
col3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Good!  +1   Could add `to_numpy()` to convert the series to a numpy array as in the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using numpy

You can [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) `df1` to check against `df0`:

```py
np.any(df1[None, :] == df0, axis=0)
# col1     True
# col2    False
# col3     True
# dtype: bool
```

Note that this assumes `df1.index` and `df0.columns` have the same order. If not, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) first:

```py
np.any(df1.reindex(df0.columns)[None, :] == df0, axis=0)
```

---

#### Using pandas

Use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to check whether a given `df1` value [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) the corresponding `col` of `df0`:

```py
df0.apply(lambda col: col.isin([df1[col.name]])).any()
# col1     True
# col2    False
# col3     True
# dtype: bool
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
array=[]
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c','d'],'col2':['b','c','e','f'],'col3':['d','f','g','a']})
df1 = pd.Series(['b','g','g'], index=['col1','col2','col3'])
for i in range(1,4):
    col = 'col'+str(i)
    array.append(df0[col].str.contains(df1[col]).any())
print(array)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you'd like a quick one liner using list comprehension:

`[df1[i] in df0[i].unique() for i in df1.index]`

And if it needs to be an array:

`np.array([df1[i] in df0[i].unique() for i in df1.index])`

The output is:

`array([ True, False,  True])`