# Add/subtract value of a column to the entire column of the dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image]

I have a DataFrame like this, where for column2 I need to add 0.004 throughout the column to get a 0 value in row 1 of column 2. Similarly, for column 3 I need to subtract 0.4637 from the entire column to get a 0 value at row 1 column 3. How do I efficiently execute this?

Here is my code -

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((df.shape[0], len(df.columns)))).round(0).astype(int)
for (i,j) in zip(range(0, 5999),range(1,len(df.columns))):
    if j==1:
        df2.values[i,j] = df.values[i,j] + df.values[0,1]
    elif j>1:
        df2.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i,j] - df.iloc[0,j]
print(df2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend for you to read about broadcasting: [What does the term "broadcasting" mean in Pandas documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29954263/14627505). Pandas was not designed to iterate through - this is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df2 = df - df.iloc[0]
```

---

#### Explanation:

Let's work through an example.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5))
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 2 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 3 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |

`df.iloc[0]` selects the first row of the dataframe:

```py
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

This is a Series. The first column printed here is its index (column names of the dataframe), and the second one - the actual values of the first row of the dataframe.

We can convert it to a list to better see its values

```py
df.iloc[0].tolist()
```

```py
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then, using broadcasting, we are subtracting each value from the whole column where it has come from.