# Python Pandas For Loop with If/then condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, data-analysis

I have the following dataset which I'm looking at banking approval data by two different date months (EOM Date = is when it was uploaded & Approve Date = When facility was actually approved).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["1/08/23","1/08/23","yy1"], 
                    ["1/08/23","1/08/23","yy2"], 
                    ["1/08/23","1/07/23","yy3"],                                            
                    ["1/07/23","1/07/23","yy4"], 
                    ["1/07/23", "1/06/23", "yy5"], 
                    ["1/07/23", "1/07/23", "yy6"], 
                    ["1/06/23", "1/06/23", "yy7"], 
                    ["1/06/23", "1/05/23", "yy8"], 
                    ["1/06/23", "1/04/23", "yy9"]], 
                columns= ["EOM Date","Approve Date","Facility Id"])
```

The desired output is if the 'EOM Date' and 'Approve Date' match id like that in the output. Currently, I am able to create this by using the numpy `np.where(EOM Date == Approve Date, Facility Id, 0)` etc. However, I need to do this in a loop format.

Output

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["1/08/23","1/08/23","yy1"],
                    ["1/08/23","1/08/23","yy2"],
                    ["1/07/23","1/07/23","yy4"], 
                    ["1/07/23", "1/07/23", "yy6"],
                    ["1/06/23", "1/06/23", "yy7"]], 
                columns= ["EOM Date","Approve Date","Facility Id"])
```

| EOM Date | Approve Date | Facility Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/08/23 | 1/08/23 | yy1 |
| 1/08/23 | 1/08/23 | yy2 |
| 1/07/23 | 1/07/23 | yy4 |
| 1/07/23 | 1/07/23 | yy6 |
| 1/06/23 | 1/06/23 | yy7 |

Comment: "*i need to do this in a loop format*" -> why? this is much less efficient than `np.where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `iterrows()` to loop over the dataframe (list comprehensions format)

```
lst = [val for i, val in df.iterrows() if val['EOM Date'] == val['Approve Date']]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

But the efficient way is to use `np.where` or broadcasting

```
df = df[df['EOM Date'] == df['Approve Date']]
```

Both will produce

```
  EOM Date Approve Date Facility Id
0  1/08/23      1/08/23         yy1
1  1/08/23      1/08/23         yy2
3  1/07/23      1/07/23         yy4
5  1/07/23      1/07/23         yy6
6  1/06/23      1/06/23         yy7
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you mind explaining what broadcasting is?

Comment: @svenvuko That's a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29955358/5168011

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it in a loop this will print all rows where EOM Date matches Approve Date. However, as @mozway pointed out np.where is more efficient.

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['EOM Date'] == row['Approve Date']:
            print(row)
```