# Why does dividing columns by another column yield NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a Pandas dataframe `df`.

```
df.info()
---
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 1 to 3
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   0       3 non-null      int64
 1   1       3 non-null      int64
 2   2       3 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(3)
memory usage: 96.0 bytes
```

| Survived | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pclass |  |  |  |
| 1 | 80 | 136 | 216 |
| 2 | 97 | 87 | 184 |
| 3 | 372 | 119 | 491 |

Dividing 1st and 2nd columns with the 3rd column cause Nan. Why is it?

```
df[[0, 1]].div(df[[2]], axis=0)
```

| Survived | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pclass |  |  |  |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Comment: Broadcasting of pandas occurs in operations on series and dataframes. chk what is broad casting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954263/what-does-the-term-broadcasting-mean-in-pandas-documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because divide by one column `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with different column name `2` like `0,1` columns names.

```
print (type(df[[2]]))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (df[[2]])
            2
Survived     
1         216
2         184
3         491

#divide by 0 column from rename
print (df[[0, 1]].div(df[[2]].rename(columns={2:0}), axis=0))

                 0   1
Survived              
1         0.370370 NaN
2         0.527174 NaN
3         0.757637 NaN
         
#divide by 0 column from rename
print (df[[0, 1]].div(df[[2]].rename(columns={2:1}), axis=0))

           0         1
Survived              
1        NaN  0.629630
2        NaN  0.472826
3        NaN  0.242363
```

For correct output need divide by `Series` by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
print (type(df[2]))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (df[2])
Survived
1    216
2    184
3    491
Name: 2, dtype: int64

out = df[[0, 1]].div(df[2], axis=0)
print (out)
                 0         1
Survived                    
1         0.370370  0.629630
2         0.527174  0.472826
3         0.757637  0.242363
```